# Making a custom field editable based on the editable state of another field in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to enable and disable a new custom field dependent on the editable state of an existing field.  I don’t know the exact rules for when the other field is enabled or not.  I was trying to detect the enabled state of the other field in different events (e.g. RowSelecting, RowSelected), but its Enabled property seems to always be true, even though when the field is shown in the grid, it is not editable by double clicking.  Any ideas? The way I'm determining enable state of a field is with this code...

```
    protected bool? IsFieldEnabled(PXCache cache, object row, string fieldName)
    {
        var attr = cache.GetAttributesOfType<PXUIFieldAttribute>(row, fieldName).FirstOrDefault();
        bool? isEnabled = null;

        if (attr != null)
        {
            isEnabled = ((PXUIFieldAttribute)attr).Enabled;
        }

        return isEnabled;
    }
```

FYI, The field enabled state I'm trying to mimic is LotSerialNbr for SOShipLine and SOShipLineSplit which appears in the Shipments detail tab and the Allocations dialog.

Comment: FYI, The field enabled state I'm trying to mimic is LotSerialNbr for SOShipLine and SOShipLineSplit which appears in the Shipments detail tab and the Allocations dialog.

Comment: That sort of thing could usefully be added to the question. Try the "edit" link :-)

Comment: to be editable a field must be editable and the row must also allow update (ViewName.AllowUpdate). While your field is showing as editable, is the entire row disabled (no fields in the row can be changed)? Also the RowSelected event should work, but maybe you need to run your logic after the base rowselected if you are doing a graph extension?

Comment: The row is updateable, and the other field is sometimes editable, which I'm trying to mimic. The RowSelected event is in a graph extension, yes, where I'm trying to determine if a field is enabled.  I'll try checking it after the base RowSelected as you mention.

Comment: I added an invoke of the base handler to my RowSelected handler, but that didn't seem to help.  I did notice this time that for the initial load of the page the existing field is Enabled=true, but then loading the same page again Enabled=false. So disabling maybe occurred after RowSelected?  So the second time my extended RowSelected is fired, it then works to set my custom field Enabled=false to match; however the new field on the page still behaves the same way and is editable as if it didn't do anything.  Maybe setting it in the RowSelected is too late?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I was finally able to affect my custom field's editable state by handling it in its FieldSelecting handler. When I check the other field's Enabled state and set my new field's Enabled state both in the FieldSelecting, it now mimics as I had originally wanted; and with the initial page load as well. Below is the code for anyone interested...

```
    protected void SOShipLine_UsrMACID_FieldSelecting(PXCache cache, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e, PXFieldSelecting InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
        if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
        {
            InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
        }

        var row = (SOShipLine)e.Row;
        bool? isSerialNumberEditable = IsFieldEditable(cache, row, "LotSerialNbr");

        if (isSerialNumberEditable != null)
        {
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOShipLineExtension.usrMACID>(cache, row, isSerialNumberEditable.Value);
        }
    }

    protected bool? IsFieldEditable(PXCache cache, object row, string fieldName)
    {
        var attr = cache.GetAttributesOfType<PXUIFieldAttribute>(row, fieldName).FirstOrDefault();
        bool? isEnabled = null;

        if (attr != null)
        {
            isEnabled = cache.AllowUpdate && ((PXUIFieldAttribute)attr).Enabled;
        }

        return isEnabled;
    }
```